Unable to create Gameobjects in unity editor (in editor mode not in play mode) whenever something changes in a file
I am trying to create gameobjects in Unity editor usingFileSystemWatcher to watch a communication.txt. Now whenever some changes are made in the file the function is called properly, but it does not create an object. In the console I can see till execution of Debug.Log("Working"); command. Following is my main code:
// My main code

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class EditorHello
{
    private static string filePath;
    private static FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher;

    static EditorHello()
    {
        // Define the path to the communication file
        filePath = Path.Combine("E:/temp", "Communication.txt");

        // Initialize a file watcher to monitor changes to the file
        fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fileWatcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
    }

    private static void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Read the content of the file
        string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        // Perform actions based on the content
        if (content != "GeneratePrefab")
        {
            Debug.Log("Generating prefab...");
            letsgo();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Content does match.");
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Test")]
    private static void letsgo(){
        PrefabGeneratorEditor.GeneratePrefab();
    }
}



// Prefab Generator Code
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace UnityEditor
{
    public class PrefabGeneratorEditor : Editor
    {
        [MenuItem("Tools/Generate Prefab")]
        public static void GeneratePrefab()
        {
            Debug.Log("Working");
            // Create a parent GameObject to hold the cubes
            GameObject parentObject = new GameObject("PrefabParent");
            Debug.Log("Done1");

            // Loop through 10 GameObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                // Instantiate a new cube GameObject
                GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

                // Set the cube's position as a child of the parent object
                cube.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);

                // Set a random position for the cube within the parent's bounds
                cube.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-10f+2*i, 0, 0);

                // Create a new MaterialPropertyBlock
                MaterialPropertyBlock propertyBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();

                // Set a random color in the MaterialPropertyBlock
                propertyBlock.SetColor("_Color", Random.ColorHSV());

                // Apply the MaterialPropertyBlock to the cube's renderer
                cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().SetPropertyBlock(propertyBlock);
            }
            Debug.Log("Done");
        }
    }
}

I tried running them via menu items and it was working fine (Both menu items). All objects were created, however when making changes to file objects are not created. (Checked in hierarchy they are not being created, not out of screen). In console I am getting only:
Generating Prefabs
Working
Iam not getting any error or warning.
